# I am getting error when i use tool:openDrawer. \why?

Tags: android

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/nev_menu"
        />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**> When I remove "tools:openDrawer="start""  i didn't get any error.**

> enter code here
>
> The error is: Unable to open navigation drawer (Details)    Tip: Try
> to refresh the layout.
>
> Details -> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found
> with gravity LEFT     at
> androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1736)
> at
> androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1722)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.util.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:56)
> at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.support.DrawerLayoutUtil.openDrawer(DrawerLayoutUtil.java:59)
> at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.support.DrawerLayoutUtil.openDrawer(DrawerLayoutUtil.java:53)
> at
> android.view.BridgeInflater.postInflateProcess(BridgeInflater.java:577)
> at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.postInflateProcess(RenderSessionImpl.java:702)
> at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.postInflateProcess(RenderSessionImpl.java:707)
> at
> com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:338)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:396)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:209)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:608)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:734)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/nev_menu"
    />
```

with this:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/nev_menu"
        />
```